# Squid Log Rotation and Sarg

Tags: squid

We have just setup squid as our proxy, and i was going to use Sarg to analyze the log files. I had initially set the Squid logs to rotate everyday so they dont get huge. The problem is i cant see an option in the squid config to read a folder full of squid log files (say *.log).

Is there an easy way to do this or am i going to have to write a bash script or something to process them all into one before i get squid to read it?

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first things first. The software that rotate your logs probable isn't squid itself. Most probably is logrotate. Second. why do you want squid be able to read the full squid log folder: is Sarg who need it to read the *access.log* file. And AFAIK Sarg can process only *access.log*
So you need to go into logrotate config and change it to fit your needs. If you have problems with the size logrotate has an option for compressing logs.